# convert_encoding is screwing up Spanish-language characters

Tags: templating

Standard "when article has no summary, output the first 200 characters of the body minus HTML" logic going on here. We're implementing some Spanish-language features for the first time and, while special characters are stored fine in the database (utf_unicode_ci collation) and they output fine on the front end when convert_encoding isn't applied, they come out garbled when convert_encoding is applied.

My code is:

```
{{ item.articleBodySpanish.type('bodyText')[0].bodyText|striptags|convert_encoding('UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES')|slice(0, 200)|default('Lee mas') }}...
```

I have an entry where the database contains this for articleBodySpanish:

```
<p>Empuja sus puños contra los postes y sigue insistiendo en que ve a los fantasmas.&nbsp;Empuja sus puños contra los postes y sigue insistiendo en que ve a los fantasmas.</p>
```

With the code above, the output I get is as follows:

```
Empuja sus puÃ±os contra los postes y sigue insistiendo en que ve a los fantasmas. Empuja sus puÃ±os contra los postes y sigue insistiendo en que ve a los fantasmas.
```

If I remove the **|convert_encoding('UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES')** the output becomes this, so I can't even just take it out to moot the issue:

```
Empuja sus puños contra los postes y sigue insistiendo en que ve a los fantasmas.&nbsp;Empuja sus puños contra los postes y sigue insistiendo en que ve a los fantasmas.
```

What can I do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need any `convert_encoding` here. From your results, the special characters are coming out fine, it's your `&nbsp` that is your problem.

For this to go you can use the `|raw` Twig filter.

Comment: Hi and thanks. Sorry for the delay, had to pivot to another project. I did try {{ item.articleBodySpanish.type('bodyText')[0].bodyText|striptags|raw|slice(0, 200)|default('Lee mas') }} but it still gives me the version with good special characters but uninterpreted &nbsp; ... what am I missing? Thanks again.

Comment: ahh, I didn't actually realize that |raw had to be the last filter. that did it.